# What corresponds in flutter to a ForEach Block in SwiftUI?

Tags: flutter, swiftui

and I wondered how I can make a column with children for each item in an array, which is **NOT A LISTVIEW.BUILDER**.

UPDATE: More Information: I have an Array of Objects (of an own class), this array is optional that means It could have nothing in it. It would be great If it could be dynamically, but I would be also okay if this is not possible.

Comment: Please clarify a little bit your question. For example, what is the type of array you have? An array of widgets, an array of objects, or some primitive type? Do you want it staticly displayed, or change dynamicly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of [Dart 2.3](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#lists) you can use collection for's as follows:

```
Column(
    // will be repeated for every element in myList
    children: [for (MyClass obj in MyOptionalList) 
                   Text(obj.name),
              ], 
),
```

As the list being an optional, you can use the [null safety operators](https://dart.dev/null-safety) for that, and give a default value of an empty list:

```
for (MyClass obj in (MyOptionalList ?? []))
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like a "for in" the widget tree? like this:

```dart
final items = List<String?>.generate(10, (index) {
  return index != 3 ? '$index' : null;
});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
    children: [
      for (var item in items) item != null ? Text(item) : Container()
    ],
  );
}
```